# Why does sudo fail inside docker complaining about nosuid?

Tags: mount, sudo, docker

Running `sudo` inside a Docker container produces the error

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

Permissions for `sudo` are set correctly:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 149080 gen 18  2018 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Also, the root filesystem is not mounted as `nosuid`.  (`mount | grep nosuid` does not include `/` as a mount point.)

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 7):

According to this [GitHub post by asbe](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36730#issuecomment-460777179),

> Containers on one host could sudo just fine, but on a nearly equivalent host the error occured. Finally figured out that the cause was because the problematic host used "overlay" as storage driver and the other "aufs". Both docker installations had moved /var/lib/docker to a drive mounted with "nosuid". Turns out "overlay" respects the "nosuid". **Just making sure that /var/lib/docker was mounted on a disk with "nosuid" removed resolved all issues.** (Curiously - this does not happen with the setup using "aufs")

(Emphasis added by me.)

Indeed, I was mounting Docker's `data-root` (by default `/var/lib/docker`) from another drive with the `nosuid` option enabled.  I disabled `nosuid` with this command on the host:

```bsh
sudo mount -n -o remount,suid /path/to/mountpoint
```

Then `sudo` worked after restarting the container.

**Determining `/path/to/mountpoint`**: The path `/path/to/mountpoint` is the mount point containing your `data-root`. To first determine the `data-root` directory, run `docker info | grep "Docker Root"`. Then use `df` to find the corresponding mount point in the `Mounted on` column. For example, if `docker-root` is `/home/docker/data` and `du` shows a mount for `/home` (but none for `/home/docker` or `/home/docker/data`), then `/path/to/mountpoint` is `/home`.

(Thanks to @DonTintoretto for following up, helping me to expand this answer.)

Comment: I would never have thought to look at the disk where the docker storage directory was. thank you!

Comment: How do I know what's the " /mount/for/var/lib/docker". I put "RUN sudo mount -n -o remount,suid /var/lib/docker" in my Dockerfile, but the message I get is mount: /var/lib/docker: mount point is not a directory. Even tough it exists on the machine I build the Dockerfile.

Comment: @DonTintoretto, you need to run the command on the host machine, not in Dockerfile.

Comment: As for `/mount/for/var/lib/docker`, good question. I don't remember all the details. To see which directory Docker is using, run `docker info | grep "Docker Root"`. Next you should figure out which filesystem this directory belongs to by running `df`. I think that `/mount/for/var/lib/docker` is the mount point. Perhaps someone else can confirm?

Comment: Thanks a lot @BenMares! It worked. With `docker info | grep "Docker Root"` I found that it's in `/home/docker` and with `df` I figured out that it's `/home`. Now I can sudo!

Comment: Thanks @DonTintoretto for confirming! I have reworked my answer to provide more detail.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great!

Comment: I'm having this issue myself, but in my case `/var/lib/docker` is on the root filesystem which is not mounted with `nosuid`. It's driving me a little crazy.

Comment: @DuckPuppy, do you perhaps define a different `data-root` in your `/etc/docker/daemon.json`?