Docker fails with "effective uid is not 0" on ubuntu
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 and I try to run the following command :
docker buildx \
  build --platform linux/arm64,linux/amd64 \
  --tag data-cli \
  --build-arg PYTHON_VERSION="$(cat cli/.python-version)" \
  --file cli/Dockerfile .

This command fails with this error
 => ERROR [linux/arm64 2/9] RUN sudo apt-get update     && sudo apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends awscli libc-dev gcc postgresql libpq-dev zip     && sudo apt-get clean     0.2s
 => CANCELED [linux/amd64 2/9] RUN sudo apt-get update     && sudo apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends awscli libc-dev gcc postgresql libpq-dev zip     && sudo apt-get clean  0.0s
------
 > [linux/arm64 2/9] RUN sudo apt-get update     && sudo apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends awscli libc-dev gcc postgresql libpq-dev zip     && sudo apt-get clean:
0.108 + sudo apt-get update
0.138 sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
------
WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load

From this question, I understood that the issue was with my host filesystem.
But when I check for the mount point of my docker I find / (same for /usr/bin)
> docker info|grep "Docker Root"
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker

> df /var/lib/docker
Filesystem                        1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 980211368 38735352 891610288   5% /

> df /usr/bin
Filesystem                        1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 980211368 38736072 891609568   5% /

But / is not mounted as no exec
> mount |grep 'on / '
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)

I don't quite understand the issue here

Are you running docker buildx or sudo docker buildx? Also, is your / really mounted with nosuid? That seems odd, why? And where did you see it was a bad idea to disable it? I am not an expert on this, but I don't think I have ever seen a system where / was mounted with nosuid (which is completely anecdotal, you couldbe right).

I am using docker buildx without sudo.
I've seen here https://askubuntu.com/a/956758/1606432 that it is not a good idea to disable nosuid

But why did you enable it in the first place? The post you linked to doesn't show a / with nosuid. And I am having trouble thinking of why that would be wanted (kinda surprised it even works, to be honest). Is your /usr/bin/ also on this / partition? And are you sure you have your / mounted with nosuid? Please edit and add the output of mount grep 'on / ' to your question.

Good question, it looks like you are right, it is not mounted as noexec (see edit in question). Then I don't understand the meaning of my original error message

And is /usr/bin under / or is it a separate partition. The error is about /usr/bin/. Please [edit] the question and give us more context. Show us the exact command you ran, try and figure out of the error is from the host machine or perhaps something internal to the docker image? Can you build different images?  Where is sudo coming from? Could you perhaps have a sudo command in the build script and that is what is failing?

Added more context

Thanks! Please don't add "Edit" sections though, they make it very hard to follow what you are saying. Instead, just incorporate the new details as though they had always been there. We have an edit history and we can check that if needed, but the next person to read this shouldn't need to go through the history, they should just get a clear question (and yes, we know we have loads of rules... sorry)

Anyway, while I don't really know docker at all, that looks like your issue is inside the docker environment and not outside it. The sudo apt-get commands you are running are supposed to be run in the docker image, right? Check how docker's internal / is mounted.

The commands are indeed supposed to be launched inside the docker container, but from this question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/546823/689500) I understood that the issue was with the host filesystem.

What mount options are in effect on the host for /var/lib/docker?

I think I put it in the question (unless I didn't understood yours) :
> df /var/lib/docker Filesystem                        1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 980211368 38735352 891610288   5% /
